# Django settings differences between local and deployment server

Tags: python, django, settings, importerror, openshift

I have a problem setting my Django application for deployment on openshift and testing locally.

Here is my structure

```
root_folder/
    my_project/
        anoter_app/
            urls.py
            views.py
        my_project/
            settings.py
            urls.py
            views.py
        manage.py
    application.py (to tell openshift where my settings file is: my_project.myproject.settings)
```

So for it to work on the deployment server, in the settings, the ROOT_URL_CONF is:

`myproject.myproject.urls`

and in my url file, the view must be reached as `myproject.myproject.views`

But when I want to work locally, I have to change the ROOL_URL_CONF as `myproject.urls`
and the views are reached with `myproject.views`

How do I make it work both locally and on the deployment server with the same settings?

Thank you

Comment: What development environment are you using? And how do you start the local development server?

Comment: What do you mean by development environment? I use eclipse with the PyDev plugin, and it stars the server by running manage.py runserver, i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it, the problem was that the folder and the app had the same name.
I renamed the app and now i dont'have to do myproject.myproject

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file named local_settings.py, at the bottom of your settings.py add:

```
try:
    import local_settings
except:
    print 'CAUTION -- NOT USING LOCAL SETTINGS!'
```

Put any settings you need to override on your local environment in your local_settings.py file.

Comment: I alreay do something like that, but that's not really the problem.
The problem is that to include something, i have to do myproject.myproject.views for example, and this everywhere, on the local server, and on openshift, just myproject.views.